# apt-get update is not working - Could not resolve 'cusxwtc-mwg4'

Tags: apt, updates, repository, dhcp, static-ip

I have an issue where the apt-get update command is not working correctly.

Eg below is part of the output of the command `sudo apt-get update`

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease Could not resolve 'cusxwtc-mwg6'
Err:3 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ InRelease Could not resolve 'cusxwtc-mwg4'
```

I have tried the command host -v cy.archive.ubuntu.com and it verifies the domain name is resolved.

I have also noticed that in each failed repository retrieval i can see the Could not resolve 'cusxwtc-mwg4' which doesn't make any sense. I have tried searching for it but i get no results.

The same message is shown (Could not resolve 'cusxwtc-mwg4') if i also try to install anything using apt-get.

What does the cusxwtc-mwg4 or cusxwtc-mwg6 mean and how can this issue be resolved?

I am using a static address IP config during the above issue but the issue is fixed if i use a dhcp configuration.  But uaing static address is a requirement for me.

Comment: Can you ping http://security.ubuntu.com

Comment: yes i am able to ping it

Answer (score 0):

This is related to McAfee Web Gateway installed in my organizations corp network.

I have overcome this issue by adding the following(replace domain with corps domain)

```
dns-search example.com
```

In the `/etc/network/interfaces` file